# Cambiar de color según valor de consulta

Tags: php

tengo un alert que me muestra la cantidad de empresas que tengo registradas en el sistema, deseo cambiar el color de fondo dinámicamente según el número obtenido de la consulta; como por ejemplo: Si supera las 10 empresas dejarlo en el verde que tiene por defecto, si es menor a 10 que se pinte de naranja. Eh intentado con este código pero no logro conseguir el resultado.

```
  <div class="row mt-3">
                        <?php 

                        if ($fila < 10) $color = '#135c1a';
                        if ($fila > 6) $color = '##f6990d';
                        

                        ?>

                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="alert text-uppercase font-weight-bold" role="alert" style="; color: #fff; letter-spacing: 2px;">
                        Cantidad de empresas: <span class="float-right">
                            <?php 
                            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM proveedor where estatus = 1";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                                    echo  $fila['total'];
                            ?>
                                
                            </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Adjunto imagen de como se ve naturalmente el fragmento de código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero evalúas `$fila` como entero y luego le asignas un arreglo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo veo varios problemas en tu código.

1. Parece que **estás asignando el color antes de conocer los resultados**, guardándolo además en una variable `$color` que nunca usas. También la comparación es errónea, porque verificas si es menor, no mayor que 10 y el segundo color es erróneo porque usas dos veces `##`:

   ```
                   if ($fila < 10) $color = '#135c1a';
                   if ($fila > 6) $color = '##f6990d';
   ```
2. Además de eso, `$fila` no representaría el total de filas de la consulta, sino un recurso con los datos obtenidos.
3. También tienes error en las etiquetas del `<div class="alert ...>`, por ejemplo el `style` no se escribe así `role="alert" style="; color:` ...

Tu código debería funcionar de este modo, salvo errores adicionales en otra parte:

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM proveedor where estatus = 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $total=$fila['total'];
    #Asignamos el color según un ternario
    $color=($total>10) ? '#135c1a' : '#f6990d';
?>

   <div class="row mt-3">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="alert text-uppercase font-weight-bold" role="alert" style="color: <?php echo $color; ?>; letter-spacing: 2px;">
                        Cantidad de empresas: <span class="float-right">                                
                            </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Aquí: `style="color: <?php echo $color; ?>;` indicamos que tenga el color asignado según la cantidad de filas.

### Recomendación

Se considera una mala práctica usar funciones y estilos in-line. Eso hace que el código HTML sea totalmente dependiente y que el programa sea más difícil de mantener al no respetar el principio de responsabilidad única. Es mejor usar clases `.css`  y aplicar los estilos desde un archivo `.css`. Así, si tienes cientos o miles de archivos HTML y quieres cambiar cualquier estilo, modificas el archivo `.css` una sola vez, sin tener que buscar cientos o miles de archivos HTML para modificarlos.

Comment: Muchas gracias justo lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

La validacion la tienes que hacer dentro de tu ciclo, por otro lado no veo que tu codigo recorra todos los valores insertados dentro de tu tabla.

Te recomiendo hacer un while para evaluar linea por linea cada uno de tus registros;

Ejemplo:

```html
?php

<!-- tu query -->
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM proveedor where estatus = 1";

<!-- indicas que tu query lo quieres ejecutar en tu conexion previamente configurada $conn -->
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

<!-- Si tu query recibe mas de 0 resultados entonces haces tu instruccion -->
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    <!-- Fila por fila vas obteniendo los resultados y muestras los que necesites unicamente dentro de este while -->
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

        <!-- El UTF8_Encode no es necesario sino estas usando utf8 en tu bd -->
        if(utf8_encode($fila['total'])<6){
        ?>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
        //agregas tu span para el color <6
        ...

        <?php
        }else{
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        <!-- agregas tu span para el color <10 -->
        ...

        <?php
        }
        ?> 
        <!-- cierras tu if * ademas puedes crear tantos else if como sean necesarios -->


    <!-- perfectamente pudo estar dentro de las llaves de php de arriba pero quiero separartelo para explicartelo -->
    <?php
    }
// si tu conexion y tu query esta bien entonces todo se ejecuta perfectamente y resibes tu $result

mysqli_free_result($result);

} else{

// Si no ningun error en tu query ni tu conexion pero tampoco hay registros en tu tabla te muestra esto

echo "No se encontró ninguna fila";

}
} else{

//Si tienes un error en tu consulta o conexion aqui se despliega un hint

echo "$sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);

 }
?>
```

Esto deberia de solucionar tu duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda